# PHP Parse.com get all columns for a pointer

Tags: php, parse-platform

i'm using Parse.com with the library for PHP and i wanna get all columns for a pointer to Product in my class RepProdMae, my code is below, but i don't know how obtine all columns, thanks for your help.

```
    $pqry = new parseQuery('RepProdMae') ;
    $pqry->whereInclude("Product") ;
    $pqry->wherePointer('productId','Product', 'lqf4mmpOgS') ;
    $pres = $pqry->find() ;

    print_r($pres) ;
```

this print_r return:

```
 stdClass Object
 (
     [results] => Array
        (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [userId] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [__type] => Pointer
                        [className] => _User
                        [objectId] => 3YjQkMwrvf
                    )

                [productId] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [__type] => Pointer
                        [className] => Product
                        [objectId] => lqf4mmpOgS
                    )

                [comments] => nothing
                [createdAt] => 2014-07-16T01:44:41.549Z
                [updatedAt] => 2014-07-16T01:44:41.549Z
                [objectId] => 6VzG9K1BTS
            )
       )
   )
```

And my product class have more colums, my query array is :

```
Array
(
  [where] => {"productId":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Product","objectId":"lqf4mmpOgS"}}
  [include] => Product
  [limit] => 100
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter for the Include method should be the column name which is a pointer, not the class name which is pointed to.

Try changing this line:

```
$pqry->whereInclude("productId") ;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @Fosco with this change works fine

Comment: Sorry I have other question, if i wanna go to a second or third level is posible? eg, my first class RepProdMae have a pointer to Product this have a pointer to SubCategory and this other for Category, how can do with WhereInclude or what other thing can do, considering also i can't use a value for my actual query for a wherePointer $pqry->wherePointer('productId.CategoriId','Category', thisquery.ProductId.CategoryId) ;

Comment: I don't think you can go multiple levels with the Where, only the Include ( productId.categoryId ).  For querying on nested objects, you'd have to use a method for 'matches query' which I'm not sure is implemented in the library you're using.